# Apache2 + Solr: Tomcat or Jetty?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, jetty, solr

I have an (Ubuntu 10.4) server running Apache2 web server. So far so good, I have a few extensions setup just the way I hoped for, I'm happy.

But now I'd like to try out Apache Solr because I'd rather work out the quirks to setup a nice robust environment while we only have a few hundred thousand records, it's easier than when we have a few billions.

---

Given it seems you need more than just Apache2 and the JDK to run it (right ?), I have to choose between Tomcat and Jetty, but I never used either of them (well I used Tomcat 10 years ago, but it's been so long, I forgot everything about it).

My initial choice was Tomcat because that's what most tutorials use and it has the most documentation about running it in parallel with Apache2; however Jetty seems to be an interesting alternative and it's even used by [the official tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html).

---

**So what would be better to use with Apache2 and Solr, Tomcat or Jetty ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tomcat is older and very stable with solr in combination.

jetty is newer and is a bit more complicated to administer. jetty can be configured to run in many ways(embedded, diy by importing the class etc)  as opposite to tomcat which has all predefined (logs, scripts, libraries etc).

it all depends on your confidence level in the end. i have tomcat and solr, but running as well jetty with other apps.